# I am wanting to create my own version of findIndices in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am new to Haskell and I'm not too comfortable with the syntax. I am basically trying to write my own version of findIndices from Haskell. This is what I have so far:

```
findIndices :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Int]
findIndices pred [] = []
findIndices pred (x:xs) = [n | n <- [0..length xs], pred x == True]
```

I am stuck on the list comprehension part. I want to be able to ask if the pred x == True on all of the elements of the list, but this will only ask it on the head of the list. Is there any way to recurse through the entire list to ask if pred x == True?

Comment: `x` is the first element of the list, `xs` are the remaining elements, so `pred x` will always be `True` or always be `False`, regardless of the value for `n`.

Comment: Using `expr == True` is exactly the same as using just `expr`, as the result is of type `Bool` anyways

Answer (score 1):

`x` is the first element of the list, `xs` are the remaining elements, so `pred x` will always be `True` or always be `False`, regardless of the value for `n`.

You can work with [**`zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip) to enumerate over two lists concurrently and construct 2-tuples, so:

```
findIndices :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Int]
findIndices pred xs = [i | (i, x) <- zip [0..] xs, pred x]
```

Here `(i, x)` are a 2-tuple where `i` is a (zero-based) index, and `x` an element from `xs`. We thus filter on `pred x`, and in that case yield the index `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip [0..] xs` to get a list of (index, element) tuples, then apply your predicate :)

```
findIndices :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Int]
findIndices pred xs = [i | (i, x) <- zip [0..] xs, pred x]
```